# Recommended Server Specs for GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, wms, server, specification

we serve our Geographic data via our flagship application [Dorset Explorer](http://explorer.geowessex.com). This uses OpenLayers and GeoServer to serve our Geographic data, including OSM and OS Basemaps and a mass of other data such as Aerial Photography, Schools etc.

My question is, what sort of Server Specs should we be using for GeoServer. We will only have available to us one server for delivery of tiles via WMS (and perhaps in the future we may be using some WFS on it as well). We get between 100 and 200 users per day, but this will hopefully start rising as soon as we are confident that the servers will hold up! Is it just a matter of stick in the highest specs we can afford or are there some limits or theoretical maximums.

Any pointers would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

100-200 users a day are (normally) nothing, a notebook can take that kind of load 
if the map is not complex.

General guidelines:

- get enough memory (at least 8GB) but don't give it all to GeoServer
- use Intel CPUs, not AMDs, as JAI native extensions work faster on Intel
- try to get two servers and set them up in cluster for high availability (2 quad core should be enough), if the load goes up you just need to add more servers
- make sure your data is properly configured for performance: http://demo.geo-solutions.it/share/foss4g2011/gs_steroids_sgiannec_foss4g2011.pdf
- if you have enough disk space consider tile caching for the layers that do not change often
- do some load testing to see how far you can get with some test hardware and scale up the servers according to the expected load.

Answer (score 6):

Choosing the right server is always a hard thing to do because in a short time your service may become very popular, turning your thousand dollars hardware useless.

-Since every application (even if they use the same software stack) has it's own demand, my advice is to run some stress tests in a cloud based server, like amazon AWS. The costs to run those tests is insignificant.

-It's possible to make a relation between AWS (for example) hardware and commodity hardware so you can try different configurations for different number of users and requests to have an idea on how both the hardware and the software will perform in the future, examples: [here](http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/Stress+Testing) and [here](http://www.slideshare.net/novum.limitis/mapserver-vs-geoserver).

-If it's an option for you, IMO stick to the cloud server you can scale it up and down whenever you want.